# Dart Limiting simultaneous connections

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have an interesting problem with Dart running in command line mode - its too fast!

The situation is that the code has to access a web site and retrieve a list of files that can be downloaded, It then downloads each file to write to the local disk.

The problem is that each download operation is running asynchronously and the downloads starts failing with errors like 'SocketException: OS Error: The semaphore timeout period has expired.' and 'Connection closed before full header was received'. As far I can determine the OS on my PC is failing to open all the required connections or possibly the web server is been swamped.

How should I change the design to limit the number of simultaneous connections been made?

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages wich should make this easy:

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pool
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rate_limit
- [forEachAsync of quiver](https://github.com/google/quiver-dart/blob/e63e0e061900c91e07bf06a79581b955523351b9/lib/src/async/iteration.dart#L67)

Comment: The [rate_limit](https://pub.dev/packages/rate_limit) package appears to be badly out of date now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to that what suggested Günter Zöchbauer, I can advise the following option (lightweigh software semaphore):

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:semaphore/semaphore.dart';

Future main() async {
  var maxCount = 3;
  var running = 0;
  var simultaneous = 0;
  var sm = new LocalSemaphore(maxCount);
  var tasks = <Future>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    tasks.add(new Future(() async {
      try {
        await sm.acquire();
        running++;
        if (simultaneous < running) {
          simultaneous = running;
        }

        print("Start $i, running $running");
        await _doWork(100);
        running--;
        print("End   $i, running $running");
      } finally {
        sm.release();
      }
    }));
  }

  await Future.wait(tasks);
  print("Max permits: $maxCount, max simultaneous runned: $simultaneous");
}

Future _doWork(int ms) {
  // Simulate work
  return new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: ms));
}
```

Output:

```
Start 0, running 1
Start 1, running 2
Start 2, running 3
End   0, running 2
Start 3, running 3
End   1, running 2
Start 4, running 3
End   2, running 2
Start 5, running 3
End   3, running 2
Start 6, running 3
End   4, running 2
Start 7, running 3
End   5, running 2
Start 8, running 3
End   6, running 2
End   7, running 1
End   8, running 0
Max permits: 3, max simultaneous runned: 3
```